# Associate an input value with an array element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code, but it does not work correctly:

```js
let item = document.querySelector('#item');
let price = document.querySelector('#price');
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

let numb = [25, 15];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(input, el => {
    let i = +el.value;

    let res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(input, (sum, e) => {
      return sum + +e.value
    }, 0);

    if (el.value) {
      item.textContent = res;

      numb.forEach(elem => {
        price.textContent = elem * i;
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<p id="item">xxx</p>
<p id="price">xxx</p>
<input class="input" type="number">
<input class="input" type="number">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
```

I need the value of each input to be associated with the first element of the array, multiplied by its, and the total amount from two inputs was added. That is, the first input is associated with the first element of the array and in order.

Comment: You mean to say you are getting incorrect calculation value? How you want the output?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, multiplying inputs in order by your numb array and then adding them, then :

```js
let item = document.querySelector('#item');
let price = document.querySelector('#price');
let total = document.querySelector('#total');
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

let numb = [25, 15];
let elements = [item, price];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let s = 0;
  input.forEach((el, i) => {
    const res = el.value*numb[i];
    elements[i].textContent = res;
    s += res;
  });
  total.textContent = s;
})
```

```html
<p id="item">xxx</p>
<p id="price">xxx</p>
<input class="input" type="number">
<input class="input" type="number">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
<p id="total">xxx</p>
```